# Facebook ShareDialog com.facebook.FacebookException

Tags: android

I am trying to share to facebook from my app I followed this tutorial bascially copy and paste

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/#setup

but when I run the example the error I get back is

```
Error: com.facebook.FacebookException
```

That is it with no more details. I have triple checked by app hash and it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using openForPublish instead of openForRead which is counter intuitive but still works. The Facebook Share Dialog doesn't need publish permissions to work